# How to prove that if a graph G have n vertices and m edges such that n > m + 1, then G is not connected

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-writing

So far I know that by the **Handshake Lemma** the sum of all its vertex degrees is equal to twice the number of edges.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n deg(v_i) = 2e$$

And the **Euler's Formula**, the sum of the number of vertices, edges, and faces equal 2 for Planar Graphs.

$$v - e + f = 2$$

Which doesn't apply on this statement. What can I do in order to prove this statement?, I tried to do it by contrapositive but I have no hay to prove the graph is connected, and direct proof.

Comment: Here is one possibility: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vmrUr2fCsN0

Answer (score 1):

To strictly prove it, I'd need your definition of being connected.
But just simple thinking: To be connected you need a path, that goes through the whole graph and therefore at first every vertex needs an edge, but also every "inner vertex" has to have two edges (so that not only these two vertices are connected). So strictly said, you can do induction over the vertices, where you prove "To be connected a graph needs at least e=v-1 edges".
$v=1$ ok, $n=2$ ok.
For every new vertex you add, you need a new line to connect it.
That's it.